# return whole self invoking functions

Tags: javascript

How can I return the whole object of the self-inv-function without returning every functions manually?

**I want to try with the following solution which should normally work, however, it does not work:**

```
var publish = (function() {
   var pub = {};

   pub.hello = function() {
      return "test"
   };

   return pub;

}());
```

now "pub" must be callable by subscribe:

```
var subsribe = (function(pub) {

   function hello() {
      return pub.hello();
   };

}(publish));
```

I loaded both files in the browser (pub first).

However:

Debugger says: ReferenceError: pub not defined.

Comment: You mean without specifying each method you want to expose? Dont think thats possible.

Comment: A property can't be both public (accessible) and private (inaccessible) at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to write them like this:

```js
var publish = (function() {
  var pub = {};

  pub.hello = function() {
    return "test"
  };

  return pub;

})();


var subsribe = (function(pub) {

  function hello() {
    return pub.hello();
  };

  console.log(hello());
})(publish);
```

However, keeping a global reusable collections of functions can be accomplished in other ways, more elegantly maybe :) (separate file with export, singleton decorated with those methods)

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

There's no mechanism in JS to get a list of variables in the current scope.

Even if you could, it probably wouldn't be a good idea as there would be no way to distinguish between public and private variables.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a mechanism but you can do something like this:

```js
var publish = (function() {
  const me = this;
  let publicMethods = ['hello', 'bye'];

  // private
  function _hello() {
    return "test";
  };

  function _bye() {
    return "end test";
  };

  publicMethods.forEach((methodName) => {
    let privateMethod = eval('_' + methodName);

    Object.defineProperty(me, methodName, {
      get: function() {
        return privateMethod;
      }
    });
  });
  return this;

}());

console.log(publish.hello);
console.log(publish.bye);
console.log(publish.hello());
console.log(publish.bye());
```

Comment: I changed the code above: I used pub as local variable, bind all methods and return that, however, it does not work.

Comment: @nimo23 you did something wrong since my sample works :)

Comment: I did not take your version, look above. I changed the whole code and use a variable "pub" which holds all functions and returns it, so it must be public for others. however, did not work..